# Challenge restructuring XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<SalesOrders>
    <Header>
        <CustomerID>456554</CustomerID>
        <BuyerID>312</BuyerID>
        <OrderNbr>S392392</OrderNbr>
    </Header>
    <Item>
        <Item>E565-14</Item>
        <Quantity>65</Quantity>
        <Price>33.45</Price>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Item>G916-22</Item>
        <Quantity>654</Quantity>
        <Price>655.22</Price>
    </Item>
    <Header>
        <CustomerID>156557</CustomerID>
        <BuyerID>35</BuyerID>
        <OrderNbr>S394545</OrderNbr>
    </Header>
    <Item>
        <Item>GS654-88</Item>
        <Quantity>78</Quantity>
        <Price>2.11</Price>
    </Item>
</SalesOrders>
```

I want to restructure my XML so that I have the Header & Item(s) within
Order nodes like this:

```
<SalesOrders>
    <Order>
        <Header>
            <CustomerID>456554</CustomerID>
            <BuyerID>312</BuyerID>
            <OrderNbr>S392392</OrderNbr>
        </Header>
        <Item>
            <Item>E565-14</Item>
            <Quantity>65</Quantity>
            <Price>33.45</Price>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Item>G916-22</Item>
            <Quantity>654</Quantity>
            <Price>655.22</Price>
        </Item>
    </Order>
    <Order>
        <Header>
            <CustomerID>156557</CustomerID>
            <BuyerID>35</BuyerID>
            <OrderNbr>S394545</OrderNbr>
        </Header>
        <Item>
            <Item>GS654-88</Item>
            <Quantity>78</Quantity>
            <Price>2.11</Price>
        </Item>
    </Order>
</SalesOrders>
```

I am familiar with C# and also know some LINQ.  I can't seem to find the correct example of how to do this from on-line examples that I've looked for.
Is there anyone that can post an example of how to accomplish this ?

Thank you

I apologize for not including the code.  This code actually combines many individual XML files into one XML file.  My original plan was to add the Order nodes into the XML after the final output XML file has been created.  Maybe this isn't the best method for doing this?  I'm open to all suggestions.  Here's the code:

```
public void CombineXMLFiles()
{
    string[] XMLFiles = null;
    XmlDocument CombineXMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
    CombineXMLDoc.LoadXml("<SalesOrders></SalesOrders>");
    XMLFiles = Directory.GetFiles("e:\\data\\xml\\", "529485*.xml");
    foreach (void FileName_loopVariable in XMLFiles) {
        FileName = FileName_loopVariable;
        FileInfo FileInfo = new FileInfo(FileName);
        if (FileInfo.Length <= 0) {
            File.Delete(FileName);
            continue;
        }
        XmlDocument OrderXMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
        OrderXMLDoc.Load(FileName);
        foreach (XmlNode Node in OrderXMLDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes) {
            switch (Node.Name.ToUpper) {
                case "HEADER":
                    XmlNode OrderNode = CombineXMLDoc.ImportNode(Node, true);
                    CombineXMLDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(OrderNode);
                    break;
                case "ITEM":
                    XmlNode OrderNode = CombineXMLDoc.ImportNode(Node, true);
                    CombineXMLDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(OrderNode);
                    break;
                default:
                    continue;
            }
        }
    }
    string dtStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    CombineXMLFileName = "e:\\data\\xml\\output\\" + "STC_" + dtStamp + ".XML";
    CombineXMLDoc.Save(CombineXMLFileName);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your current code that you need help with?

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: The code that I have takes many individual XML files and appends them into a single output XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Linq to XML code permutes your first XML sample into the second. If you need to cobble together the first XML out of multiple files, getting `xdoc` together may be more complicated than this.

You can trivially translate this logic into a foreach loop. There's nothing at all difficult about what you're trying to do.

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var headersWithItems = 
    xdoc.Descendants("Header")
    .Select(h => new {
        Header = h,
        Items = h.ElementsAfterSelf().TakeWhile(e => e.Name == "Item") })
    ;

var salesOrders =
    new XElement("SalesOrders",
        headersWithItems.Select(
                hwi =>
                {
                    var e = new XElement("Order", hwi.Header);
                    e.Add(hwi.Items.ToArray());
                    return e;
                }
            ).ToArray()
        );
```

Comment: Thanks Ed.  That Linq code did the trick!  I was able to output the salesOrders var to a new XML output document.  I still consider myself a bit of a novice with Linq.

Answer (score 0):

I would of done a little different using xml linq.  Just a style difference

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement salesOrder = doc.Descendants("SalesOrders").FirstOrDefault();
            List<XElement> children = salesOrder.Elements().ToList();

            XElement order = null;
            foreach (XElement child in children)
            {
                if (child.Name.LocalName == "Header")
                {
                    order = new XElement("Order");
                    salesOrder.Add(order);

                }
                order.Add(child);
                child.Remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```